# How to get the RGBA color table of a singleband raster using R?

Tags: r, raster, geotiff

Here is a raster file called [`singleband-raster.tif`](https://srv-store1.gofile.io/download/DnEnTY/singleband-raster.tif).

Using R, I can get the color table like so:

```
my.raster <- raster( "/path/to/singleband-raster.tif" )
colortable( my.raster )
```

It will give you the RGB values like so:

```
[1] "#FFFFFF" "#969696" "#FA00FF" "#F200FF" "#E600FF" # shortened for brevity
```

This is okay but what I want to get are the **RGBA** (red, green, blue, alpha) values instead of just **RGB** values. Because the raster file also have alpha values supposedly like so:

```
[1] "#FFFFFF00" "#969696FF" "#FA00FFFF" "#F200FFFF" "#E600FFFF"
```

The alpha values can be checked through a GDAL tool in the command-line like so:

```sh
gdalinfo /path/to/singleband-raster.tif
```

How to get the RGBA color table of a singleband raster using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html) says that

> The TIFF format only supports R,G,B components for palettes / color
> tables. Thus on writing the alpha information will be silently
> discarded.

(and, therefore, on reading not available)

It seems that in this case (no alpha in the file) GDAL assigns an alpha of 0 to the NA flag, and 255 to all other values. `raster::colortable` does not show that. But with the *development version* of [terra](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) (version 0.9-1) you can get what you are after

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("singleband-raster.tif")
ct <- cols(x)[[1]]

head(ct)
#  red green blue alpha
#1 255   255  255     0
#2 150   150  150   255
#3 250     0  255   255
#4 242     0  255   255
#5 230     0  255   255
#6 222     0  255   255
 
cols <- rgb(ct[,1], ct[,2], ct[,3], ct[,4], maxColorValue=255)
head(cols)
#[1] "#FFFFFF00" "#969696FF" "#FA00FFFF" "#F200FFFF" "#E600FFFF" "#DE00FFFF"
```

Comment: [Robert Hijmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635245/robert-hijmans), thanks for that info. However, that statement from GDAL made me super confused. Using their [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html), it can retrieve the correct alpha values from a TIFF. So I don't get the part where *TIFF format only supports R,G,B*

Comment: Possibly that is a 4-layer (band) TIFF file (i.e. not using a color table)?

Comment: Robert, it has only 1 band. I already attached the TIFF file in the question for reference.

Comment: I think in this case there is an alpha of 0 for NA, and 255 for all other values. GDAL assigns these, as they are not in the file.

Comment: Aw! I see. It is treated as a boolean of only `0` or `255`? That makes sense though.